# Render component inside Tabs after .map function return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, jsx

When I try to render TabPane inside a .map function I have the following issue: my component (DepartmentView) is rendered just for the first TabPane, for the next TabPane content is empty.
I am using **ANT Design** library.
My question is how can I render DepartmentView for each TabPane from the .map function?

```
 <Tabs tabPosition="left" className="tab-view-page">
  {
    data.map((item) => (
      <TabPane
        tab={(
          <CustomTabTitle
            title={item.name}
            subtitle=""
          />
        )}
        key={item.id}
      >
        <DepartmentView data={item} />
      </TabPane>
    ))
  }
</Tabs>
```

DepartmentView component:

```
<div className="main-section">
    <div className="horizontal-tabs-container">
      <Tabs className="horizontal-tabs-profile">
        <TabPane tab={<FormattedHTMLMessage id="layout.tabs.overview" />} key="overview">
          Here will be overview page
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab={<FormattedHTMLMessage id="layout.tabs.staff" />} key="staff">
          <Employees />
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab={<FormattedHTMLMessage id="layout.tabs.settings" />} key="settings">
          <Settings />
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check that you've imported antd css.

```
 import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

Comment: I imported the Ant css already and the style it's applied, but the issue still continue

Comment: Strange. I tried to reproduce the issue. I've inspected html with devtools and I see that all three TabPanes are in html.

Select first TabPane in html you have this

`code`
<div
  class="ant-tabs-content ant-tabs-content-animated ant-tabs-left-content"
 ** style="margin-top: 0%;"**
>
</div>
`code`
And selecting second TabPane you have this
`code`
<div
  class="ant-tabs-content ant-tabs-content-animated ant-tabs-left-content"
 ** style="margin-top: -100%;"**
>
</div>
`code`
I think that is the issue. But in my case it was fixed by importing antd css to component.

Comment: TabPanes are rendered in html for me too, but the DepartmentView component somehow is rendered just for the first TabPane and I don't understand why...

Comment: For other TabPanes DepartmentView is also rendered. But you don't see it because when you select another Tab (not the first one) this container  

<div class="ant-tabs-content ant-tabs-content-animated ant-tabs-left-content"  style="margin-top: 0%;" > 

has "margin-top": -100% or "margin-top": -200% and that's the problem. If you try manually inspect this element and change margin-top to 0 you will see DepartmentViews for other TabPanes. In my case it was fixed by importing antd css.

Comment: I found the issue, because I had tabs in tab i set the TabPane height to 100% and the next tabs were overflowed. I removed this css property and all works well. Thank's for the ideea to check the css file!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any syntax errors. Maybe you could check that  the `data` array is greater than 1 in length and that each `item` object has all required keys.

Comment: in return i have the code above: <div>
        {
          data.length > 0 && (
            <Tabs> data.map()... </Tabs>
          )
        }
      </div>. But it's still not working